# ASP.NET and Custom Routing to the default page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-routing

I have made the routing in asp.net to work correctly .But still if i type the Address with Default.aspx it's surpassing my routes and hitting the Page.

2)As well as For the First request of my application is not hitting the route handler .ie when
`http://localhost:8080/` (using visual studio server) is not hitting so i am not able to render the first page correctly

Comment: What happens when you go to `http://localhost/`?

Comment: @ataddeini its going to default.aspx

Comment: Is it setup as a "Web site" or "Virtual Application" in IIS? If it's a "Virtual Application", you have to specify the name in the address bar, like: http://localhost/my-webiste

Comment: i am using visual studio server .. editing the address http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to handle default.aspx? If you refer to the root of your website like:

```
Response.Redirect("~/");

// or

<a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a>
```

The address is resolved correctly. So what if someone wants to type in default.aspx, since that's the only way they will get there and have default.aspx show in the address bar. What exactly is the problem here?

As for your second question, it might be a configuration problem in the Web.config. Make sure you have the following in WEb.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: k.. may be Default.aspx i dont want to handle.. I have written custom routeHandler It's not called when the first request hits the application.